# Clean Install of Ubuntu 14.04 on Dell Latitude e6420. New working HDD

Tags: 14.04, boot

I attempted to perform the subject task. Configured the boot to be UEFI and Sata to be AHCI. Mine is i5 Vpro with 4GB of ram. Error is no bootable drive detected after successful install with no error. Live USB is done using UUI

Comment: ...and what did you expect?

Comment: I expected it to run smoothly and boot correctly. Isn't this what I should expect?

Comment: Obviously not. Turning UEFI on after the fact isn't a good idea, unless that was the 'subject task'.

Comment: Well, you are more than welcome to let me know how I can do it and how to do the subject task and I am all ears :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you say you "configured the boot to be UEFI", please make sure that your PC has an
EFI based BIOS, because DELL Latitude e6420 is an older model, which may have legacy BIOS.

Boot from Ubuntu installation media, open GParted - View - Device Information.

In case it has Legacy BIOS, make sure that the disk has a `msdos` partition table.
In case it has an UEFI BIOS, make sure that the disk has a `gpt` partition table.

When it does not match, create a new matching partition table and reinstall.
More comprehensive information on how to prepare the disk you find [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu/743098#743098).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will do it now but shouldn't I erase the disk first or keep the partitions made during my previous attempts and work as per the guide?

Comment: @azyaser : When you create a new partition table, the whole disk will be erased automatically. :)

Comment: Well it has GPT partition table so I guess it is UEFI.

Comment: @azyaser : You cannot see whether the PC has EFI or legacy BIOS in GParted, this you can check when you boot into BIOS ... so when your PC has an EFI based BIOS, create a gpt partition table, when it has a legacy BIOS, create a msdos partition table. :)

Comment: Where do I check that in bios. I have two options legacy and UEFI

Comment: @azyaser : No, you don't have 2 options, the PC has EFI or legacy BIOS - the options you mean are most probably the USB boot options - I suggest to first try installing in EFI mode and when it doesn't work, in legacy mode as next attempt - important : don't forget to create the matching partition table before. :)

Comment: Hello. Thanks for this. I am still getting this error and don't know why. I installed it on an old Dell Inspiron and it worked with no issues.

Comment: @azyaser : You're welcome ! Good to read that you got Ubuntu installed on the DELL Inspiron and this is the proof that it must be a hardware related thing with the DELL Latitude (as I already assumed on your other topic) and as you told me there that it is an old company PC, maybe there is a protection against changes which has to be unlocked in BIOS ... but with this we can't help you further. If you still want to  install Ubuntu on that notebook, unfortunately only you can figure it out and try it all out yourself. :)